# How to get tracking confidence from KCF Tracker in opencv-contrib-python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-tracking

When tracking an object using the [KCF Tracker](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dff/classcv_1_1TrackerKCF.html) from opencv, is there a way to get the actual confidence value of the tracker outputted?

I have searched around and this page was the closest I could find: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/1123. I believe [maxVal on line 344 in trackerKCF.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/1123/commits/4ae95b6e2a233f5e5f1c8aa2542b203ab6cf730e#diff-4a7b65a5100de1b61dd71b464f0fd44257f950262462f4808c1f239453dd31c4R344) is the variable I am looking to have outputted but cannot find any functions to actually obtain it.

I am using opencv-contrib-python version: 4.5.5.64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, that value is not shared.  As you pointed out, you can see in the OpenCV source that the value is calculated in a local max_val variable and not persisted or shared in any way.  Of course, you could edit the code to save max_val in some public class variable, and then re-compile, if you want to go to that much trouble.